# PHP convert string into variable ,check if it's value is not empty , compare to other values

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to convert a string into a variable. I know that this question has been already asked, but I can't get it to work. I need help. I have a few variables that I get through POST like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$prename = $_POST['prename'];

$array_var = array("name","prename");
$array_var_count = count($array_var);       

for($t=0;$t<$array_var_count;$t++){
    $var="$".$array_var[$t];
    //echo("<script>alert('".$var."');</script>");
}
```

Now `$var` should get the value of :first:(name) and second of:(prename) because  `$var==("$".$array_var[$t])=> $var=$name;`.
This means it should take the value of `$name = $_POST['name'];`.
Yet it doesn't. This is why I think I have to convert it into a variable. I'm not quite sure. I'm new in php. And I also want to check if `$var` is not empty, like this:

```
for($t=0;$t<$array_var_count;$t++){
    $var="$".$array_var[$t];
    ..............................
    if(!empty($var)){
    ..............................
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script has some issues. If I understand correctly, this might suit you:

```
$array = array(
    "first_name" => $_POST['first_name'],
    "last_name" => $_POST['last_name']
);  

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($value != ''){
        echo "<script>alert('$key = $value');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @splash58 Doh! Sorry, I use JS all day long... Thank you!